# Typescript cannot find IdleDetector

Tags: typescript

I want to use `IdleDetector` but Typescript has no types for it and say `Cannot find name 'IdleDetector'`, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your `global.d.ts`:

```
interface IdleDetector {
    addEventListener(type: "change", listener: (this: IdleDetector, ev: { userState: "active" | "idle", screenState: "locked" | "unlocked" }) => unknown, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    start(options: { threshold: number }): Promise<void>;
    screenState: "locked" | "unlocked";
    userState: "active" | "idle";
}

declare const IdleDetector: {
    new(): IdleDetector;
    requestPermission(): Promise<"granted" | "denied">;
};
```

It is not 100% correct, but for my use it was good enough.